# Calling a member function using function pointers from another class's instance

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class Base;
typedef void (Base::*function)();
class Base
{
public:
    function f;
    Base()
    {
        cout<<"Base Class constructor"<<endl;
    }
    virtual void g()=0;
    virtual void h()=0;
};
class Der:public Base
{
public:
    Der():Base()
    {
        cout<<"Derived Class Constructor"<<endl;
        f=(function)(&Der::g);
    }
    void g()
    {
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Function g in Derived class"<<endl;
    }
    void h()
    {
        cout<<"Function h in Derived class"<<endl;
    }
};
class Handler
{
    Base *b;
public:
    Handler(Base *base):b(base)
    {
    }
    void CallFunction()
    {
        cout<<"CallFunction in Handler"<<endl;
        (b->*f)();
    }
};
int main()
{
    Base *b =new Der();
    Handler h(b);
    h.CallFunction();
    getch();
}
```

I am getting an error while trying to call a member function in a derived class using function pointer declared in the base class. The function pointer is declared public and is actually used by another class Handler. I have used an unsafe typecast in this code. (function)(&Der::g). Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754799/c-pointer-to-virtual-function - use `Base::g` instead, that cast you have is invalid.

Comment: function f != pointer. So *f is incorrect.

Comment: @Laurence Thanks for the reply. But why is f not a pointer. Isn't it a function pointer. I am sorry, if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` doesn't appear to be in scope in `Handler::CallFunction`.  I'm guessing you meant to call the `b->f` using `b` as `this`, as it `(b->*(b->f))()`.  When I make this change, your code compiles and prints out something sane.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's working the way i want it. But I didn't understand why it was giving me the error earlier. Since f is a public member why can't i access it in Handler? What was happening when i had written (b->*f)()?

Comment: @sajas: Member pointer syntax is always confusing. In `Handler`, the name of the member is `b->f`, just like any other member variable. (A longer version would be `function bf = b->f; b->*bf();`.) The `b->*` sequence says "call one of b's member functions" but the thing after the "*" must be named from `Handler`'s perspective, not `b`'s  - that arrow doesn't "reach inside" `b`.